# Hardness of a special case of maximum matching

Tags: computational-complexity

Input:

A set of N Users $\{u_1, ..., u_N\}$. A set of M products $\{i_1, ..., i_M\}$.

Every pair $(u,i)$ is associated with the probability of u purchasing the product i, $p_{u,i}$.

Task: Assign each user with exactly $K$ products (notation: $(u,i) \in A$) so that the following objective function is maximized
$$
\sum_{i: \exists u \ni (u,i) \in A} \left(1-\prod_{u: (u,i) \in A}{(1-p_{u,i})}\right)
$$
Question: Is this problem NP-Hard?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). SOme of this write up could use cleanup to make it look and read better. Regards

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a version of the "weapon target assignment problem", see e.g.
http://web.mit.edu/sloan-msa/Papers/1.5.pdf
. It seems that no exact algorithms are known.

Comment: Link outdated above

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of the weapons-target assignment problem:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weapon_target_assignment_problem